# Connection error when remotely managing 10.9 OS X Server (SSL Handshake)

Tags: network, macos, server.app, ssl

I am managing a Mac Mini with OS X Server (10.9) at the office and I got everything running perfectly. However, since some days ago I have lost the ability to connect remotely to the server using the `server.app` from my computer. I am still able to connect through screen sharing though (locally running server app works fine).

The system logs throw an SSL handshake error every time I try to remotely admin the server. I have looked through here and apple discussions but found no one with that same error code. It seems to me like a certificate problem but I have not been able to figure it out. All other services work great (file sharing, profile manager, ssh, etc.)

> Dec 19 10:04:52 server.XXX.private servermgrd[80208]: Got error -9805 for SSLHandshake  remote address is 192.168.XXX.XXX:34545
>   Dec 19 10:04:52 server.XXX.private servermgrd[80208]: Got error -9805 for SSLHandshake  remote address is 192.168.XXX.XXX:34801
>   Dec 19 10:04:52 server.XXX.private servermgrd[80208]: Got error -9805 for SSLHandshake  remote address is 192.168.XXX.XXX:35057

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so after two weeks of not using this feature I tried again and it has now worked (not sure why). The log file says: Jan  3 09:13:14 server.XXX.private collabd[329]: [CSUserSessionServiceBase.m:48 4398000 +0ms] Detected Magic Superuser Auth Token

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after two weeks of not using this feature I tried again and it has now worked (not sure why). The log file says:

```
Jan 3 09:13:14 server.XXX.private collabd[329]: [CSUserSessionServiceBase.m:48 4398000 +0ms] Detected Magic Superuser Auth Token –
```